# How to show a bootstrap modal success message on successfully added product to the cart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have written a jquery for adding product to the cart and this is the partiallistofproduct.cshtml file.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
            <div class="features_items">
                <h2 class="admin-title text-center"></h2>
                <!--Partial list of Products-->
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="features_items">
                        <!--features_items-->
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                    <div id="@item.ProductID" class="productinfo text-center">
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("ReadProductDetails", "Home",new {id=item.ProductID })">
                                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.ProductImage)" alt="" />
                                        </a>
                                        <h2>Rs @item.Price</h2>
                                        <p>@item.ProductName</p>
                                        @if (Session["UserName"] != null)
                                        {
                                            <p hidden id="userid">@Session["UserID"].ToString()</p>}
                                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnSession" data-value="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["Name"]" />
                                        <input id="AddToCart" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-overlay">
                                        <div id="@item.ProductID" class="overlay-content">
                                            <h2>Rs @item.Price</h2>
                                            <p id="productid">@item.ProductID</p>
                                            <a class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--features_items-->

                }
                <!--Pagination part-->
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pageSize = Model.PageSize }))
                showing @Model.FirstItemOnPage to  @Model.LastItemOnPage of @Model.TotalItemCount Products
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is the script file to add the product to the cart.Here i am able to add the product to the cart.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //on click on add to cart class this will perform
        $('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
            //checking user is logged in or not otherwise redirect to login page
            var sessionValue = $("#hdnSession").data('value');
            var aaa = parseInt($(this).closest('div').prop('id'));
            if (sessionValue != false) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Account/AddToCart',
                    data: { //Passing data
                        UserID: $("#userid").html(), //Reading text box values using Jquery
                        ProductID: $(this).closest('div').prop('id'),
                        Quantity: 1
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    //on success message will show as an alert
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null && data.success) {
                            alert(data.responseText);


                        } else {
                            // DoSomethingElse()
                            alert(data.responseText);

                        }

                    },
                    //on failure error message will occur
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                //redirection to login page
                window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Login", "Account")");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here i want to show a bootstrap modal success message with successful adding the product to the cart. I dont know how to use bootstrap modal to show the success message.
So please help me to show a bootstrap modal success message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add modal in your view which you want to show on after successful addition of products to cart and add `style:display:none`
2. then inside Ajax Success function just write

   `$("#modal-Id").modal()`;